# What mapping software can print large battlemaps for RPGs?

Tags: images, mapping

Years ago, I used [Dundjinni](http://www.dundjinni.com/) to create battlemaps for the RPG game that I ran. However, each individual map was restricted in size such that it corresponded to the size of a piece of normal 8.5" x 11" paper, and this meant I had to create a bunch of different maps, eyeballing them so that they'd be able to be printed separately and then joined up, which was frustrating and also required taping the map pieces together if I wanted to lay out a full dungeon level, or even just a large room. The software gave me very nice looking maps but simply couldn't create maps of the size I wanted.

I've got access to a large plotter at work which allows me to print out full-sized battlemaps (a little over 3' wide, however long I want). So far I've used a workaround where I convert maps to images, join all the images together in something like Paint, then print that image out to the plotter, but even this requires a lot of trial and error to get the scale right so that 1 square = 1 inch. I'd rather just find some mapping software that would handle all this for me.

Something like [Dungeongrapher](http://www.dungeonographer.com/) is a nice mapping utility and useful for creating dungeon maps like you'd find in a module, but is a little too basic and colorless for the types of battlemaps I want. I want full color with nice art so that when I set it on the table and plop the minis down, it really comes alive.

Is there any mapping software out there that supports creating full-color, detailed battle maps of large size such that they can be printed on a plotter?

Answer (score 2):

The [ProFantasy Suite](http://profantasy.com) supports custom grid dimensions, and is generally full-featured with good-looking assets. The downside is that it's quite expensive – $40 for the dungeon designer alone.